# How do I open Google Sheet document using GDrive iOS 8 Document Picker extension

Tags: ios8, google-drive-api, document, picker

I'm trying to open Google Sheet documents using the GDrive iOS 8 Document Picker.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to make these documents available for picking; they always show up as inactive.

I first tried to specify standard MIME types. I specified the following document types in my UIDocumentPickerMemuViewController initialiser:

```
kUTTypeText
kUTTypeSpreadsheet
kUTTypeUTF8TabSeparatedText
```

However, no Google Sheet documents are available. So, OK, maybe I need to use a Google specific MIME type. I see a list here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/mime-types

So, I add every MIME type on that list

```
application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
application/vnd.google-apps.audio
application/vnd.google-apps.document
application/vnd.google-apps.drawing
application/vnd.google-apps.file
application/vnd.google-apps.folder
application/vnd.google-apps.form
application/vnd.google-apps.fusiontable
application/vnd.google-apps.photo
application/vnd.google-apps.presentation
application/vnd.google-apps.script
application/vnd.google-apps.sites
application/vnd.google-apps.unknown
application/vnd.google-apps.video
```

Still nothing.

So, is there a trick to get these files to be available from the GDrive Document Picker?

Comment: I any1 got how to do this. Please share.